# Do road signs showing a country and a city as destinations really exist?

Tags: driving, road-trips, factoids, road-signs

I was watching the movie "*The Day of the Jackal (1973)*", where Jackal was driving on a road, past this road sign.

[image]

It shows one country(**Italie**) & one city(**Paris**) on the road sign. I never saw a country name on a road sign.

Do road signs showing one country and one city exist?

Comment: [Here is one with a country and a street](https://www.interstate-guide.com/images805/i-805_ca_st_05.jpg), if that's of interest.

Comment: There are some in Canada pointing to the USA. I dont remember which road but I've seen this many times.

Comment: This sign is oddly specific. Normally, it's just "Paris" and "toutes directions".

Comment: Yes, they exist. Here in Vienna there are a lot of them pointing towards nearby Czech Republic, Hungary and Slovakia in addition to the local towns and cities.

Comment: While this kind of signs are not uncommon, it is very unlikely that the combination is Paris and Italy, as there are many cities in France that will be 'in the way' and will be signposted. Best I heard of is/was the sign 'last exit before Belgium'.

Comment: Aroung my place, there are several roadsigns indicating countries (Austria, Switzerland), though they do not spell out the country name but use the country codes in a white oval that is/was also used on cars. [An example can be found here](https://www.memmingen.de/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_Autobahnkreuz-Schild_4299c0d2d8.png)

Comment: @Willeke: "it is very unlikely that the combination is Paris and Italy, as there are many cities in France that will be 'in the way' and will be signposted." - but the city does not have to be the nearest one to the signpost. I remember that in Portugal, signposts pointing towards Lisbon seemed to be omnipresent even on the other side of the country.

Comment: New York interstate pointing to Canada. https://www.interstate-guide.com/images190/i-190_ny_st_07.jpg

Comment: Of course. How else are you going to sign them?  Signs show the clearest and most succinct labeling they can.

Comment: @Willeke The sign is marked Route Nationale 7. That runs from Paris to the Italian border, so the sign is giving the two endpoints. Paris Metro lines are signposted in the same way, for example.

Comment: @SimonRichter Paris and Italy are the two endpoints of Route Nationale 7. If you're not close to Paris, then it's not true that you go one way for Paris and the other way for everywhere else.

Comment: Before we go into an endless debate, I'd say there are a couple of things to consider here. The first, it that the OP asked "do road signs showing a country and a city as destinations really exist?", and the answers, well...answered this, so problem solved.

Comment: But about the discussions on Paris, RN7 and stuff like that...the film was sometime using fake road signs to give the viewer a clear feeling of where the scene was, so we have no certainty about that specific sign being real. And the movie has been shoot at the beginning of the '70, so I wouldn't spend too much time discussing if it's real or not, unless someone here is a road signs manufacturer and has access to a '70 catalogue of them. And, even today, road signs can be totally crazy sometime, so I wouldn't loose too much sleep on that "Paris/Italie" sign...

Comment: Are you asking about **ONE** sign doing both, exactly as on the picture, or **several** ones combined on same pole?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sure they do, here's a few:

[image]
[image]
(credit [ojdo.de](https://www.ojdo.de/wp/2016/05/stockholm-impressions/), CC licensed)

However, these are uncommon for anything larger than city states, because drivers are usually trying to go a specific city, not an entire country.  In the second sign from Stockholm's ferry terminal, you'll note that "Tallinn" (Estonia), "Riga" (Latvia) and "St. Petersburg" (Russia) are listed individually, but "Finland" is listed as a country because there are services from Stockholm to both Turku and Helsinki.

Comment: Here's one for the North Americans: http://www.niagarafallsreview.ca/2017/03/26/despite-recent-concerns-fewer-canadians-are-denied-entry-at-us-land-border And another http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-a-road-sign-on-the-canadian-side-of-niagara-falls-directing-tourists-15079119.html

Comment: in the United States, there are various Canada/Wherever signs as you get close to the border.

Comment: I wouldn't say these are uncommon for anything larger than city states, at least not in Europe. For example, here is a [freeway sign from Austria that shows not only "Slowenien" (Slovenia) as destination](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Süd_Autobahn_A2_Knoten_Villach_20090603.jpg), but even has additional signs for D (Germany) and Slo (Slovenia). Note that this is not even close to Germany, Germany is on the other side of Austria than Slovenia. Wikimedia Commons has many more fotos with countries shown as destination on this freeway.

Comment: It is likely because the country (border crossing) is not really on a city. It is a warning that by going in that direction you cross a border. The city is irrelevant in this scenario.

Comment: I saw a road sign in Jordan pointing to Iraq and Saudi Arabia. I believe the other direction had cities within Jordan.

Comment: There are signs on the beltway of Ljubljana (Slovenia) that list Austria, Italy, and Croatia all together (as well Slovenian cities and local destinations).

Comment: "However, these are uncommon for anything larger than city states" - well, Finland is larger than a city state.

Comment: @TomTom: "It is likely because the country (border crossing) is not really on a city." - various border crossings are on or near actual townships, but rather small and unknown ones (other than for having a border crossing). In that case, anywhere else in the destination country is a more likely destination for most travelers than exactly the border town.

Comment: Laser focus answers, this is why I seriously fallen LOVE with **Stackexchange**.

Comment: Your second example is cheating, I feel. That sign says "Ferry this way; it goes to Finland", not "Finland this way."

Comment: @DavidRicherby For the sake of the question, I think it's good enough. "I never saw a country name on a road sign." Finland is definitely a country name.

Comment: The first example is not a good one, because Monaco is both a city and a country, and there's no way to know if the road sign is pointing to the country of Monaco (and is thus a good example) or to the city of Monaco (and thus a bad example).

Comment: @MikeScott Monaco the city and Monaco the country are _exactly the same thing_. You can't point to one without pointing to the other. It's like saying, "I can't tell whether your name refers to you or to your parents' son." There is no context in which you are not both of those things; there is no context in which Monaco is not both a city and a country.

Comment: @Mast I think you're being overly literal. There's a street called France Street in Batley in northern England. Surely that doesn't count.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You can walk from France to Egypt in the northern Netherlands (["Frankrijk" to "Egypte"](http://www.fietsenwandelweb.nl/route/view/291248/Wandelroute-Tussen-Frankrijk-en-Egypte.nl)), so no, that's not what he meant. Boards stating the border is in 1km probably don't count either. But ferry boards state the name of the country (not the street) and actually point towards said country. How's that not what the author asked?

Comment: @Mast I guess you're interpreting the sign as "This way to Finland; you'll need to take the ferry" which I guess counts; I'm interpreting the sign as "This way to the ferry; the ferry goes to Finland", which I think doesn't count. At the very least, it doesn't seem as clear as the sign in the question, which is incontrovertibly "This way to Paris; this way to Italy."

Answer (score 24):

Yes, they do exist. The first situations that come to my mind are:

- On motorways when you are approaching the border and there are not many "big cities" ahead. For example: [Sign for France](https://www.google.es/maps/@41.5599182,2.2657367,3a,75y,67.35h,94.3t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sc0ZXuXewXXTG_ZMdKwEsvQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=ca&shorturl=1)
- When you're close to the border you might not want to
  cross it inadvertently (for example, until a few months ago, I could
  drive a 125cc motorbike in Spain but not in France). For example: [Sign for France](https://www.google.es/maps/@42.7753022,-0.3682256,3a,46y,310.62h,85.07t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s2NjDP5mMHEISf3O1O0rrGw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=ca&shorturl=1)
- When the route is not obvious or you have more than one option you could also see a sign somewhat far away from the border. For example: [Sign for Andorra, going through toll or toll-free road](https://www.google.es/maps/@41.5549389,1.9960008,3a,75y,274.6h,99.48t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1svWWHUbhYB-DKaKYRbSBgvg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=ca&shorturl=1)

Comment: +1 I immediately thought of the "Francia" signs too :) And I think we all agree that France is "larger than city states"!

Answer (score 19):

There exists plenty, even if they are way common than in old times.

---

Scope of road signs is not always the same, but generally they should help you move to a destination and at the same time give you a general sense of your position. And you, as a driver, back in the days, had no GPS, few highways, and was traveling by landmarks.

In this case, for example:

- He is in France, near the border, on a secondary road
- The big sign you are referring at, points him to the Route Nationel 7 and in the direction of Paris. Paris is an important landmark, so when you pass the border and you are not on a major road, you are likely to use it as a reference point to get oriented. It's like the sign is saying "North-North West", but in a human readable form.
- The other sign simply points to Italy. When you are near a border you don't get the list of options, because usually there are none: you can cross the border at a specific point, and all that you can do is to go to Italy. So there is no "Italy - Turin" and "Italy - Naples", because there is only a single gate. If you want to go to Rieti from France your first problem is to go to Italy, so a sign saying "Italy" is more than enough
- Last but not least: there is a small sign on the right, that you didn't notice or just ignored, and that is not appearing in the picture. It's a local sign pointing at the road to -I think- Menton. So, the big sign give you hints on how to get out of the local road and go in the direction of two mayor landmarks, and the small local sign help you to find your way around locally.

And just remember this is the border in France ages before GPS, Schengen, highways (at least in France) and so on. It's not like today, that you can cross the border everywhere, on a major highway connecting two nation, and things like that.

---

Ok, here we go. Sadly I couldn't find the exact one, but this is the same just in the opposite direction:

[image]

This is from the Italian side of the border.

Comment: If the sign was listing major waypoints, one might expect it to list Marseille or Nice, rather than Paris. But the more specific point is that RN7 ran specifically from Paris to the Italian border. Paris isn't just a major waypoint: it's the other end of the road. (This is consistent with, e.g. directions on Paris Metro lines always being given by naming the station at the end of the line, rather than giving a direction.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is not limited to the Paris Metro. The Washington, DC Metro also uses endpoints for direction. For example, you can ride the "Blue Line to Franconia-Springfield", which reverses direction at Franconia-Springfield and becomes the "Blue Line to Largo Town Center".

Comment: @RobertColumbia Sure, but I was pointing out that this scheme is used in France (which is where the sign is), not claiming that it's unique to France.

Answer (score 11):

There are several signs here in northern Baja California, Mexico, that reference cities in both Mexico and USA e.g. Tijuana and San Diego, and once in Tijuana most signs will have San Diego and an area or street in Tijuana rather than a city.

[image]

But there are definitely some, particularly close to the border, that have both Tijuana and USA.

One example I could find an image of easily was a pedestrian sign

[image]

Same on the other side where it may say Chula Vista and Mexico or San Diego and Mexico.

[image]